# Why did my keyboard stop working?

Tags: 11.04, keyboard

I have a machine running 11.04.  Last night, everything was working fine, but this morning when I booted it, the keyboard wouldn't work.  Pressing every key on it resulted in only one letter of input, and I could not get any key to consistently work.

I have tried replacing the keyboard, I've tried multiple USB ports with each keyboard, *not even the on-screen virtual keyboard will work.*

What's going on here and how can I fix it?

---

I just booted to a console and the keyboard worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow, I had managed to turn on SlowKeys (Login Screen -> Universal Access Preferences).

The result was that I had to hold keys for very long periods of time for them to work.  Turning it off fixed it.